# Terragrunt or Terraform define an object in variable with not known number of key/values

Tags: terraform, hcl, terragrunt

I have a list of objects (buckets) that I'd like to create with my module

```sh
  buckets = [
    {
      name                        = "my_bucket",
      location                    = "EU"
      storage_class               = "STANDARD"
      force_destroy               = false
      versioning                  = true
      uniform_bucket_level_access = false
      public_bucket               = true
      labels = {
        "app" = "my_app"
      }
```

some fields are required, (like name and location) some are not and I gave them default value in resources if not provided in here; - the full module and everything is operational, but it worked without defining 'type' in variable - so it just took everything, but my question is how do I define that object in `variable` block ?

```sh
variable "buckets" {
  #type = list(object()) #? 
  type = set(object({
      name                        = string
      location                    = string
      storage_class               = string
      force_destroy               = boolean
      versioning                  = boolean
      uniform_bucket_level_access = boolean
      public_bucket               = boolean
      labels = object({
        string = string # ?
      })
  }))
}
```

how would and object look like that has optional fields

Comment: Is this with version 0.14 and the experimental feature that enables this functionality? Otherwise, this is not possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform/issues/19898
https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/map-object-with-optional-attributes/6714

It Doesn't seem possible yet apparently..

Comment: while you're here, may I ask another question regarding terraform ? I was passing a list of objects like above to my module and all worked, but when I migrated the code to terragrunt I start getting errors saying my list is in reality a string, and I'm not sure to what should I map this string

Comment: A value of type string cannot be used as the collection in a 'for' expression.       

and with tolist() I get

Invalid value for "v" parameter: cannot convert string to list of any single type.

Comment: any idea how do I map the string to which terragrunt maps this object, back to this object ?